# input type number + ng-keypress to allow '-' sign

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, input

I have the below input type number mentioned. Along with numbers, i want some other keyboard characters to be accepted. Hence i have used ng-pattern to accept "null", ".","+" and  "-" values

It also have ng-keypress function where i have mentioned about ----> 'dash':189, 'subtract':109. These are keyboard codes to accept '-' from keyboard.

Somehow it is not accepting '-'. I tried to put various patterns so that '-' is accepted. But it doesnt.

```
<input ng-keypress="Num($event)" type="number" step=".1" ng-pattern="/^[+-]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)[\r\n]*$|^$/" ng-model="dataip"></>


$scope.Num = function (event) {
    var keys = {
        'up': 38, 'right': 39, 'down': 40, 'left': 37,
        'escape': 27, 'backspace': 8, 'tab': 9, 'enter': 13, 'del': 46,
        '0': 48, '1': 49, '2': 50, '3': 51, '4': 52, '5': 53, '6': 54, '7': 55, '8': 56, '9': 57, 'dash':189, 'subtract':109
    };
    for (var index in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(index)) continue;
        if (event.charCode == keys[index] || event.keyCode == keys[index]) {
            return; //default event
        }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Can someone please have a look and advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this ASCII table: [image]
Character code (Dec column) for `-` is 45.

Here is working JSBin: https://jsbin.com/yipigicuve/edit?html,console,output

BTW I think you don't need to set `type="number"` on input element. Please also consider inputs like `--3---8438`, currently you are accepting inputs like this. Please consider using some library like https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask.

Comment: Thanks csharpfolk.